Example API call for all years of data for a specific school returns only 'latest'. How do I get all years of data?
I'm doing research for a certificate, and have been trying get multiple years of stats for certain universities.
The data.yaml included in the "All data files" .zip download (found on this page) describes parameters to use to accomplish this for two different Higher Education Institutions:
...
{'name': 'Miami Dade College',
 'description': 'show school data for all years by id',
 'params': '/v1/schools?id=135717&all_years=true'},
{'name': 'Arizona State University',
 'description': 'show school data for all years by id',
 'params': '/v1/schools?id=104151&all_years=true'},
...

However, the returned results from these API calls only return information from year "latest".
Example results:
{'metadata': {'page': 0, 'total': 1, 'per_page': 20},
 'results': [{'latest': {'school': {'zip': '85287',
     'city': 'Tempe',
     'name': 'Arizona State University Campus Immersion',
     'alias': 'ASU Tempe',
     'state': 'AZ',
     'locale': 12,
     'address': 'University Drive and Mill Avenue',
...

I scrolled through the results but couldn't find anything referring to previous years, and did a quick search to see if I might be missing a specific key, but couldn't see anything referring to previous years:
for result in response.json()['results']:
    print(result.keys())
... 
dict_keys(['latest', 'school', 'location', 'id', 'ope6_id', 'ope8_id', 'fed_sch_cd'])

I also tried a different call to see if I could pull up Enrollment count of undergraduate certificate/degree-seeking students. According to the API documentation, and accompanying data dictionary (found here) a valid call might be something like:
'params': '/v1/schools?2014.student.size__range=100..&fields=school.name,2014.student.size'

Sending this call to the API returns a JSON with both school.name and 2014.student.size fields, but the student size field returns None:
{'metadata': {'page': 0, 'total': 4450, 'per_page': 100},
 'results': [{'school.name': 'Alabama A & M University',
   '2014.student.size': None},
  {'school.name': 'University of Alabama at Birmingham',
   '2014.student.size': None},
  {'school.name': 'Amridge University', '2014.student.size': None},
...

It could be that I'm not querying the API correctly. Could anyone help point me in the right direction?
Thank you.
